# Expected Value of choosing a specific object from n objects

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I came across a probability question I can't figure out. Any help will be appreciated.

You are given n balls of k different types. One of these types(say type 1) is the one you want. The probability of drawing a ball of type say 'x' is

|x|/n

where |x| is the number of balls of type x.

In one turn, you can pick any ball from the bag. Let us assume it is type 'x'. But before the next turn, all balls of type 'x' must be removed from the bag. So now the bag contains n-|x| balls. And then you proceed with the next turn. (Here also |x| is the number of balls of type x)

The game ends when you pick a ball of the type you want(i.e, type 1).

What is the expected number of turns I need to play to end the game?

Comment: You say $n-x$ balls, but $x$ was a type, not the number of balls of that type.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention relative probabilities of drawing different types, so I'll assume they are the same. Notice that this problem doesn't change if you take out all the balls that you'd take out doing the trial before you actually draw! This is exactly the same question as asking what's the expected number of draws from a bag of $\frac{n}{k}$ balls before you get the one you like! Thus the answer is $\frac{n}{2k}$.

EDIT: There's no precise answer that can be given based on the distribution you provided, because it depends on what the distribution is. However, my comment still holds in a modified form. The reduction is the exact same, but with the note that the drawing is non-uniform, instead it is P(drawing the representative ball for group x)=$\frac{|x|}{n}$.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but probability of drawing all BALLS is the same,i.e. 1/n. Hence probability of drawing a particular type say 'x' is |x|/n.

Comment: No problem :) I edited my answer to address that, unfortunately a more precise answer cannot be given without any information about the distribution...

Comment: I am supposed to write a program that takes the probability distribution as input and then gives the expected number of turns as output. So it must work for any possible distribution. 

Hence there must be a way to get the answer regardless of the distribution.

Comment: Ah, this is a great example of a meaningful difference between practice and theory. In theory, what I said is right, because there is no equation that tells you the answer in any meaningful way (there's something super messy one can do with sums and integrals, but it's much more complicated than just saying "the expected value is the expected value of this simpler distribution".

In practice, there is an algorithm that computes what you want, because there's an algorithm for the expected value of the distribution I reduced the problem to.

Comment: This distinction is important because in the theoretical question you don't have access to the distribution, and any answer has to apply to every distribution. In your algorithm you do.

That said, let me consider the problem again in this new light.

Comment: I don't think your reduction is sound. Initially, I know the distribution(let it be P1). Now once I take a turn, and remove |x| balls, the probability distribution for every remaining type changes, as there are only n-|x| balls left in the bag. It is no longer P1.

Comment: I'm surprised you think that @techwiz911, so let me repeat myself just so I know we are on the same page.

The asked problem and the following problem have the same answer. Let there be k balls, each with a label. The odds of pulling the ball labeled x is given by $\frac{|x|}{n}$. The game ends when you pick the ball you want. What is the expected number of turns I need to play to end the game?

Comment: Yes it is the same, the key point being that here 'n' is not constant, it will be reduced every turn. Thats what I wanted to emphasize upon.

Answer (score 0):

Better way would be to go around calculating the count the times you will have to choose K times to get desired balls.
For i steps let count be Ci 
So ans will be smthing like :
 (1*C1 + 2*C2 ....k*Ck)/(C1+C2...Ck)

Now problem is to find an efficient way to get C1,C2,C3..Ck.

So think of some Intellegent way (maybe dynamic programming or some algorithm) to get these.
And please share the method if you find one!